# declaration of a vector when calling a function and declaring me

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

In the following function, I would like to put the 100x100 values of the cos array in an unidentified way (like for the array cos[]).

```
void processing(std::vector<std::array<double, 100 >> & cos, int & index)
{
....
}
```

How to do so for vectors?

Comment: What do you mean?  Could you fill in as much code as possible and give the example input and output of the program?   Where are you stuck?

Comment: One of the outputs of the function is a vector of 100 x 100 double values. But I want to NOT specifiy in the beginning the number of values (100X100). My question: how to not specify that number in the declaration?

Comment: `vector<vector<double>>& cos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template:

```
template <typename T>
void processing(std::vector<T> & cos, int & index)
{
 ....
}
```

**EDIT** After seeing comment. If you want to only accept `std::array` of any size,
use a non-type template parameter:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void processing(std::vector<std::array<double, N>> & cos, int & index)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch! But does the use of template will kind of ignore the number of values as well as the type of vector? Shall I use then two templates?

Comment: @MelMed: Both `std::vector` and `std::array` have a member function named `size()`, which will give you the number of elements in the container.  See my update which shows what I think you are looking for.